# Grouping via key in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a multi-line form with fields `product_id`, `quantity`, `price`, `address`. There can be user-defined rows in the form. I want to group these entries via unique addresses.

`form_details=params` makes `form_details` something like:

```
form_details = {
  :product_id => [1,2,3,4,5],
  :quantity => [10,20,30,40,6],
  :price => [100,1000,200,30,2000],
  :address =>[ 'x','y','z','x','y']
}
```

I want a new hash, grouped by each unique address. So, the first time I should get is:

```
result = {
  :product_id => [1,4],
  :quantity => [10,40],
  :price => [100,30],
  :address => ['x']
}
```

The second time all details should be grouped via `address=>'y'`

And then the third and final time by `address=>'z'`.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: from where `order` comes? is it `order=>` or `order=`?

Comment: Just take it as a new variable...The result should be stored in order each time.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, please do not change code examples in the OP's question. That is considered a bad edit and needs to be rolled back. Only the OP should change their code. Making it readable is one thing, but don't change its content.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree with you, but you also reverted the edit that was made by the OP. I fixed that.

Comment: That's possible. There were several pending edits occurring at once.

Comment: @PratikBothra Have you thought about why there is this messy edit going on beween MrYoshiji, theTinMan, and me? If you have not, you are sloppy. It is also the reason you got downvoted.

Comment: Um... let's say that a bit more kindly... Please take the time to format your code, and question, so it is more readable. People answering questions are volunteers and don't want to take time to decipher hard-to-read code. The longer it takes them to understand, the less likely they are to work on it, which leads to down votes. So, help us help you, and make it as readable as possible from the start. A side benefit of this is it'll help you write more readable code, which is always a big win.

Comment: @Sawa - I really should have submitted the question in a more readable format in the first time itself. As to why so many of you are editing at the same time, I've no idea. I was trying something in irb. I will check now to make sure the question format is as good as possible. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The question is ok as far as my eyes can see....Can we now turn our focus on the answers now? :)

Comment: Sure. First show code you wrote to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too elegant, but here's one solution:

```
input = {:product_id => [1,2,3,4,5],:quantity=>[10,20,30,40,6],:price=>[100,1000,200,30,2000],:address=>['x','y','z','x','y']}

output = Hash.new do |h, k|
  h[k] = Hash.new do |h, k|
    h[k] = []
  end
end

input[:address].each_with_index do |address, index|
  input.each do |key, value|
    next if key == :address
    output[address][key] << value[index]
  end
end

p output
```

Output:

```
{"x"=>{:product_id=>[1, 4], :quantity=>[10, 40], :price=>[100, 30]}, "y"=>{:product_id=>[2, 5], :quantity=>[20, 6], :price=>[1000, 2000]}, "z"=>{:product_id=>[3], :quantity=>[30], :price=>[200]}}
```

The Hash.new sets up useful defaults for Hash keys which are not set so we don't have to put in `||=` everywhere.

The logic is simple: For every index of the `:address` array, push the `index`th value of all keys except `:address` of `input` into `output`.

Comment: Even I got a working solution, but it wasn't elegant at all. That's why I was looking for a few ideas. Thanks

Comment: One question, what is this doing exactly => output = Hash.new do |h, k|
  h[k] = Hash.new do |h, k|
    h[k] = []
  end
end.....If we just did output={}, is it totally different?